# What is wrong with my solution to a simple birthday problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I assume that many people know about the famous birthday problem, which asks for the probability of having at least 2 people of the same birthday in a group of N people (given that there are 365 days/ year).

I tried to tackle a very simple case when N = 2: within 2 people, what is the probability that they have the same birthday. I have read many reasonings and solutions online, but I still have not figured out why my reasoning to the problem is wrong. Here is mine:

Each person can have any birthday from 1/1 to 12/31. Assume that each combination of their birthday is in the form of (bday of A, bday of B),

- the combinations of the two which show they have the same birthday are: (1/1, 1/1), (1/2, 1/2), ... (12/31, 12/31). Total possibilities: 365
- the total possible combinations of the two: (1/1, 1/1), (1/1, 1/2), ... (1/1, 1/31), (2/1, 2/1), .... Total possibilities: 365 + 364 + ... + 1 = (365*366)/2

Probability of two people having the same birthday in a group of 2: 2/366

The answer is supposed to be 1/365. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Actually the total possible combinations are $365^2$. So the correct solution is $365/365^2$.

Comment: It's because the people are distinct. That person 1 has birthday on 1/1 and person 2 on 1/2 is a different situation than person 1 on 1/2 and person 2 on 1/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the bullet point

- the total possible combinations of the two: (1/1, 1/1), (1/1, 1/2), ... (1/1, 1/31), (2/1, 2/1), .... Total possibilities: 365 + 364 + ... + 1 = (365*366)/2

It's somewhat unclear what pattern you mean by "(1/1, 1/1), (1/1, 1/2), ... (1/1, 1/31), (2/1, 2/1), ....," since it seems to jump from January to February birthday pairs but only includes January pairs with a 1/1 birthday for one of the two people.  Given this, it's unclear how you get from there to the sum $365+364+\cdots+1$ for the total number of possibilities --i.e., how are you grouping the items in your list to give counts of $365$, $364$, etc.?

In any event, as others have already noted, the correct way to count the number of possible birthday pairs is to note that person A can have any of $365$ birthdays, as can person B, for a total of $365\times365$ possibilities.  A correct list would be (1/1,1/1),(1/1,1/2),...,(1/1,12/31),(1/2,1/1),(1/2,1/2),...,(1/2,12/31),..., ..., ...,(12/31,1/1),(12/31,1/2),...,(12/31,12/31), with a total of $365+365+\cdots+365=365^2$.